# Search two tables - I'm getting all the results when I want only the ones I searched for. PHP MYSQL

Tags: php

I want to multiply two values from different tables and get ONE result. Though, I'm getting the entire two tables, even mixed like I want (but I'm getting all the values). I don't even need to write on forms to search. I click run and I get everything.

(I'm aware of SQL INJECTION, don't worry. It will be taken care of)

Help me get only the values I want please! It's all about the output!!

- Table porteval: columns Id Pais Freguesia Valorm2
- Table squarefeet: columns Id M2

I want to search through Freguesia (a name) to get Valorm2 value (a number)

I want to search through m2 (a number) to get M2 value (a number)

The value I want to obtain is: Valorm2 * M2

Here is the code:

Html

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="$search1" placeholder="Property Location"/>
    <input type="text" name="$search2" size="5" placeholder="Area" />
    <input type="submit" value="Run" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>



    <title>Search</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mysql");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$search1 = @$_GET['Valorm2'];
$search2 = @$_GET['M2'];
$output = $search1 * $search2;

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM porteval, squarefeet WHERE Freguesia LIKE '%$search1%' OR M2 LIKE '%$search2$'";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>ADVISED VALUE</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Pais'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Distrito'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Freguesia'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Valorm2'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Valorm2'] * 100 . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Valorm2'] * $row['M2'] . "</td>";
                echo $search1 * $search2;
                echo $output;
                echo "<td>" . $row['M2'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure your form submits the fields as 'Valorm2' and 'M2'? according to your HTML code, it should call `search.php?$search1=&$serach2=`. You might want to put either the correct values into the `name` attribute or if you assign it to the variables beforehand, you will want to `echo` the values of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

In your form you are sending $search1 and $search1 parameters, and in your php code you are trying to access Valorm2 and M2:

Html:

```
 <form action="search.php" method="GET">
     <input type="text" name="Valorm2" placeholder="Property Location"/>
     <input type="text" name="M2" size="5" placeholder="Area" />
     <input type="submit" value="Run" />
 </form>
```

Also, I think you should use `AND` operator instead of `OR` to get more specific results:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM porteval, squarefeet 
     WHERE Freguesia LIKE '%$search1%' 
     AND M2 LIKE '%$search2$%'";
```

You don't need to use @ symbol before $_GET Variable, because it suppresses error messages and that's why your code works before.

Comment: It's just an example, you can't past directly my code, what was the relationship between porteval and squarefeet tables?

Comment: With the "OR" I get the whole table again!! Thanks for your help @YouneL

Comment: You should edit your question and give us more information about your tables schemas, what columns they have, and what you want to search in each table and try to describe the result that you want

Comment: I've already edited my question. Please see if you comprehend want I need! Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take a look @Younel

Comment: please notice that the search for a value in "M2" is a number. I tried in the form put type="number" but even so.. I cant filter the search with this second form. search 1 is starting to produce effect